# Accessing namespaced class in gem vs Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I've worked with a couple of Ruby gems and also Rails. One thing I've never fully understood is why Rails required explicit class constant references for code defined in the `/lib` folder. In a ruby gem, I could create something like this:

lib/my_gem/custom_error.rb

```
module MyGem
    class CustomError < StandardError

    end
end
```

lib/my_gem/some_class.rb

```
module MyGem
    class SomeClass
    
        def initialize
            raise CustomError
        end
    end
end
```

Whether it's an error, another class or whatever, as long as the calling class is in the same namespace as the referenced class, ruby would initialize the correct class `CustomError` in the case above. Moving to Rails, this is a different story and this code would result in an uninitialized constant error. In Rails I would have to `raise MyGem::CustomError` instead. Why is this the case? I assume it has something to do with autoloading. Is there a way around this or is this standard?

Comment: Yes, there are ways around it,  but it is use at your own risk.  You will want to read up on autoloading...https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoload-paths-and-eager-load-paths and realize it is also dependent on the version of rails you are using.

Comment: It's not possible to compare.